# SSRS 2019 Native mode is not installed with ReportServer:Service performance counter category

Tags: reporting-services, performancecounter

In my case, the performance counter category ReportServer:Service does not appear. Even after I re-install the SSRS 2019.

I tried to use the counters under categories:
MSRS 2019 Web Service
MRRS 2019 Windows Service
but none of them works, i.e. no ticks added into the performance diagram.

[image: not found ReportServer:Service counters]

Please share your solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Report Server and SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 and later do not include Reporting Services performance objects. There are .NET Framework performance counters available to provide performance monitoring for the report server.

So for 2019 SSRS, users need to rely on the below performance objects:

- .NET CLR Data
- .NET CLR Memory
- Process

Comment: From the docs, indeed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/monitoring-report-server-performance?view=sql-server-ver16#other-performance-counters